# How to draw a polyline on watchOS WKInterfaceMap?

Tags: mapkit, apple-watch, watchos

I was about to implement a polyline on my WKInterfaceMap using MKPolyline which I am using in my iOS application, but apparently apple watch doesn't have support for it.

Does anyone know some other way to do a polyline on the map using map coordinates? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WKInterfaceMap is very limited and it turns out that you cannot draw a polyline on it. You can also only draw up to 5 annotations at the same time.