# How to Draw polyline on watchOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, maps, watchos

I have to implement a polyline on my watch app but watchOS doesn't have support for it.

I have checked the below questions:

[How to draw a polyline on watchOS WKInterfaceMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48861199/how-to-draw-a-polyline-on-watchos-wkinterfacemap)

[How to draw polyline over map in apple watchOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70976040/how-to-draw-polyline-over-map-in-apple-watchos)

I have seen apps which are drawing line for Apple Watch.
Below is one example:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/pedometer/id712286167?platform=appleWatch

Is there any other way to draw Polyline in watchOS?
Thanks in advance.